# unexpected error when trying stripe with apple pay using ionic capacitor

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, capacitor

i am using https://github.com/capacitor-community/stripe to integrate in my ionic-angular app with apple pay.

the payload and code looks like below

```
const Stripe = Plugins.Stripe as StripePlugin;
Stripe.setPublishableKey({ key: 'xxxx' }); //test key
const clientSecret: string = 'xxxx'; //test secret

pay(){
 await Stripe.confirmPaymentIntent({
      clientSecret,
      applePayOptions: {
        // options here
        merchantId: 'merchant.xxx.xxx',
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'USD',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'my desc',
            amount: 1, // amount in dollars
          }
        ]
      },
    })
}
```

this shows the apple pay sheeet nicely but when i double click to confirm the payment it thorws error that i can see in the xcode console as below

```
ERROR MESSAGE: {"message":"payment failed: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds","errorMessage":"There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds"}
```

i have tried it on device and with live keys as well but no luck

Comment: You'll need to debug this on you end to see what the logs are showing.

Comment: well that is the trouble i dont see any other error than above in xcode.

Comment: @MoblizeIT Did you end up getting this resolved?  I am struggling to find a way to get apple pay working in my Ionic Capacitor project.

Comment: I got it working using the same function.

Comment: const paymentIntent = await this.stripeService.createPaymentIntentApplePayTest(this.member, 100);  const result = await StripePlg.confirmPaymentIntent(
        { clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          applePayOptions: {
          merchantId: 'merchant.mymerchantid,
          items: [{ label: 'Bread sticks', amount: 1, },],
          currency: 'NZD',
          country: 'NZ', 
        }, 
      });

 StripePlg.finalizeApplePayTransaction({ success: true });

Comment: @MadMac what is createPaymentIntentApplePayTest ?

Comment: @MoblizeIT That just creates the payment intent and returns the client secret.  You need to do that on the server.  See here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents

Comment: @MadMac
So, i implemented server side and passing await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 100, 
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card']
  });

But on final payment it fails with error. the error on stripe dashboard shows payment_method not found, any idea?

Comment: @MoblizeIT So you get the client secret back ok but it fails on the final payment from the  client?  You could try contacting Stripe support on chat it is free and sometimes helpful.  Not sure.  Check all you keys.  Are you using matching public and private Stripe keys?  Are you using a test key with a live key?  Sounds like a config issue.

Comment: @MadMac thanks buddy. if you post your above solution I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked for me.
Note that it is 1 for $1 but stripe uses 100 for $1.

```
try {
  const paymentIntent = await this.stripeService.createPaymentIntentOnServer(100);

  const result = await StripePlg.confirmPaymentIntent(
    { clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      applePayOptions: {
      merchantId: 'merchant.app.myapp',
      items: [{ label: 'Bread sticks', amount: 1, },],
      currency: 'NZD',
      country: 'NZ', 
    }, 
  });

  // then call finalizeApplePayTransaction with the result to dismiss the UI modal
  StripePlg.finalizeApplePayTransaction({ success: true });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  StripePlg.finalizeApplePayTransaction({ success: false })
}

// Server
// createPaymentIntentOnServer - this returns the client_secret
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: paymentAmount, // 100
  currency: 'nzd',
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  customer: customer.id,  // I use a Stripe Customer here which I create first
  expand: ['invoice'] 
});
```

Comment: so here is one strange thing. my code now works and pretty much what you put above. payment gets processed as well. however, the line finalizeApplePayTransaction fails with error "no valid apple pay session found", so I am still keeping this line but wrapping it in a try catch to just eat up the error.

Comment: Yeah I think maybe that is not necessary.  I was just in the testing stage so may have ignored that.  Great that you got it working.

Answer (score -2):

Stripe allows only integer as amount (1 = 1cent) so 0.5$ would be 50, and 1$ is 100.

```
const Stripe = Plugins.Stripe as StripePlugin;
Stripe.setPublishableKey({ key: 'xxxx' }); //test key
const clientSecret: string = 'xxxx'; //test secret

pay(){
 await Stripe.confirmPaymentIntent({
      clientSecret,
      applePayOptions: {
        // options here
        merchantId: 'merchant.xxx.xxx',
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'USD',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'my desc',
            amount: 50, // amount in cents
          }
        ]
      },
    })
}
```

Comment: this is actually not correct. i just tried using amount as 2.4 and apple pay screen shows it is trying to charge $2.40 rather 24 cents.  I also gave a try to use a whole number like 50 but it tries to charge $50 and fails with same error.

Comment: It actually is correct - Stripe uses integer cents - so I'm not sure what you're doing that might result in something different.

Comment: if i add single quotes around amount then it fails with {"errorMessage":"The operation couldn’t be completed. (CapacitorCommunityStripe.StripePluginError error 0.)","message":"unable to parse apple pay options: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CapacitorCommunityStripe.StripePluginError error 0.)"

Comment: actually amount can be string or decimal see https://github.com/capacitor-community/stripe/blob/e197e835c897ace806c7564817e3cb79c06f51ed/ios/Plugin/Helper.swift#L200

Comment: anyways this is not the issue. problem is somewhere else. as per stripe team more needs to be done. i am not sure what as plugin doc does not seems to require anything else